# Wordpress Jetpack Sharing Icons Broken

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

I'm using Jetpack social sharing icons. If I enable them on Front Page, Archives, etc. they work almost everywhere (Search Results, Posts, etc.).

However, they break on Post Excerpts such as when listed in a post-loop on the Blog page. Each icon shows a square where the icon should be.

Any idea what's causing this?

See behavior here: [redacted]

Click a post to see icons as they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the CSS for the genericons is not being loaded on the /blog page, but it is being loaded for an article. It looks like this in the HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="genericons-css" href="http://newman.tamucc.edu/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/_inc/genericons/genericons/genericons.css?ver=3.1" type="text/css" media="all">
```

It's a little bit of a hack because I'm not sure how exactly Jetpack is loading it's styles, but you should be able to get the icons to load on every page by adding this line to the top of your functions.php file:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'genericons', get_template_directory_uri() . '../../plugins/jetpack/_inc/genericons/genericons/genericons.css', array(), '3.1' );
```

Comment: I wrapped it into a conditional so it only runs on the page that breaks and binded it with wp_enqueue_scripts. Still hackish and probably not very permanent, but it works for me. Thanks!